# Request not being sent (XMLHttpRequest) on page load

Tags: jquery, xml, json, token

Unfortunately, this is a very vague question so if anyone can point out how to troubleshoot the problem or help me find it, i would be greatful.

The purpose of the first json request to the usertoken, and finally, when the utoken has arrived, used for the main json submission and submit a post request to the API. However, for some odd reason, it refuses to send.

This code is inserted on the thank you page, every user is direct there and it should submit once the window has been loaded. But the people who look after the API have stated that no requests have been made even with 300+ orders have been submitted.

JQUERY

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){

var myDate = "30/01/2014"; //order date - dynamic element
var n=myDate.split("/"); //split the date into correct format
var fdate = (n[2]+"-"+n[1]+"-"+n[0] ); 

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.yotpo.com/oauth/token');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (typeof cb !== "undefined") {
      cb(this);
    }
    else {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText)

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.yotpo.com/apps/ID/purchases');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send("{\n    \"utoken\": \"" + response.access_token + "\",\n    \"email\": \"email@email.com\",\n    \"customer_name\": \"Customer Name\",\n    \"order_id\": \"112897\",\n    \"platform\": \"general\",\n    \"order_date\": \"" + fdate + "\",\n    \"currency_iso\": \"GBP\",\n    \"products\":{\n        \"CODE\": {\n            \"url\": \"URL\",\n            \"name\": \"TechTalk Leicester\",\n            \"image\": \"image.jpg\",\n            \"description\": \"this is the description of a product\",\n            \"price\": \"100\"\n        } }\n}");

    }
  }
};
xhr.send("{\n   \"client_id\": \"CLIENTID\",\n   \"client_secret\": \"CLIENT SECRET\",\n   \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\"\n
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: May I ask why you are using raw XMLHttpRequest when you already pulled in jQuery?

Comment: It was recommended within the API documentation - is that no the correct way then?